# Solving functional equations programmatically

Tags: python, function, math

Given:

F(F(n)) = n

F(F(n + 2) + 2) = n

F(0) = 1

where n is a non-negative integer. F(129) = ?

How can we solve such kind of functional equations programmatically? My programming language of choice is Python.

Comment: What are the conditions on F? When n=0, F(n)=1. On what conditions does F calculate F(F(n)) and F(F(n+2)+2)?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget F is continuous on R.

Comment: Can you give a more precise description of what sorts of constraints could potentially come up when solving these sorts of problems?  It's easy to describe sequences that aren't defined everywhere if you allow arbitrary mathematical expressions.

Comment: Just for fun, the complete analytical answer according to Eureqa is `F(n) = 1 - n`, so `F(129) = -128`

Answer (score 6):

Functional equations, in their most general terms, are really really hard. It is no coincidence that pretty much every international mathematics competition features one of them, usually looking about as innocent as the one you've written. The methods of solving them vary from plain induction to infinite-dimensional Banach space analysis and a generic programming approach to solving them is very unlikely.

In this particular case, here's a straight-forward approach:

Suppose for any two integers m, n we have F(m) = F(n) = k. But then m = F(F(m)) = F(k) = F(F(n)) = n : therefore m = n and F never takes the same value on two different inputs. But we know that F(F(n)) = n = F(F(n+2)+2) - therefore F(n) and F(n+2)+2 must be the same number - which is to say, F(n+2) == F(n) - 2 == F(n-2) - 4 = ... . Now we know F(0) = 1, so F(1) = F(F(0)) = 0. But then F(129) = F(127) - 2 = F(125) - 4 = ... = F(1) - 128 = -128

So there is your solution - but a mechanical algorithm for solving any variation just doesn't exist.

Comment: You can also get the first step by the fact that `F(F(n)) = n` is the defining equation of `F` to be its own inverse. The fact that it's a bijection is then a consequence of that.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what @ivancho and @aaronasterling have said, I have been able to write this program that should do the trick:

```
def f(n):
    if not n:
        return 1
    else:
        return f(n-2)-2

>>> f(4)
-3
```

Comment if this is not what you're after